# Upload image to PostgreSQL using Java

Tags: java, sql, jsp, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to write a JSP web app that allows to upload images to a PostgreSQL database. I was following [this](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/binary-data.html) as a guide, but the image is not uploaded to the DB and the method (below) enters the catch.

This is my code so far:

```
public boolean upIm() {
    try {
        File file = new File("bg.jpg");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO images VALUES (?, ?)");
        ps.setString(1, "background");
        ps.setBinaryStream(2, fis, (int) file.length());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        fis.close();

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return false;
    }
}
```

There seems to be a problem with the FileInputStream, because the statement that goes to the db is  `INSERT INTO images VALUES ('background', ?)`   , and I've tested file.length() and it works fine.

That's it; if you need more info or more code please let me know.

EDIT: I get this stacktrace:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "images" does not exist
   Position: 13
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:363)
at bd.provaImg.upIm(provaImg.java:50)
at bd.prova2.main(prova2.java:14)
```

I think position 13 is the line in the class (not shown here) that simply instances the class in which there is this method.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained better. The method returns false when called from another class, and of course the image is not inserted into the db.

Comment: Stop catching Exception. A exception tells you what's wrong, and where. By catching it and ignoring it, you make it impossible to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Right, seems kinda obvious now. I'll do that and try to fix whatever error I'm making. Thanks.

Comment: writing image into database?! not cool, save the file in file system and save the file path in db.

Comment: "Stop catching Exception" should be "stop swallowing Exception"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace suggests that table "images" was not found. Some possibilities:
1) "images" is not the right table name; table was created with quotes
2) you need to specify database schema - either in your query (I would first try this), either in your settings file
3) something else in settings file is incorrect

Also, take a look at these posts:
- [Java SQL "ERROR: Relation "Table_Name" does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766107/java-sql-error-relation-table-name-does-not-exist)
- [PSQLException: ERROR: relation "TABLE_NAME" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034099/psqlexception-error-relation-table-name-does-not-exist)

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. The name of the table was "image" in singular and I had "images" in the Java code. It's working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is your error. Write down 1000 times on a blackboard **I will not do such again!**.

```
// BAD BAD BAD BAD BAD BAD BAD
} catch (Exception e) {
  return false;
}
```

This would be a step closer, but still **bad**:

```
// BAD BAD BAD BAD BAD BAD BAD
} catch (Exception e) {
  //NEVER do this. It hides the stacktrace, the main point of logging an error...
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
  return false;
}
```

#### Correctly:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  return false;
}
```

Or even better, with a proper logger:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
  //notice the ",e"! 99.999999% you have to log with full stacktrace!
  LOG.error("Unexpected error during file upload", e);
  return false;
}
```

You swallowed the error. This is bad. Very-very bad. Such code can be grounds for dismissal...

**And now:**

- please post the full stacktrace you get
- mark the line of the error

Comment: Well, now I get an error report but I guess I can work with that. Thank you! (I will not do such thing again!)

Answer (score -1):

database guy here. This is acceptable for class work but if you store images in a database for a real application with more than a handful of users, you will most likely be sorry and your database will be slow. A preferred pattern is to store filepaths in the database but not image files.

Comment: It's indeed a class work, I'll work with filepaths in the future.